# Как работает downcast в java

Tags: java

Я не могу никак понять как работает downcast в java.
Я знаю что он работает в тех случаях, когда мы имеем дело изначально с upcast объектом.
Типа если B extends A :

```
 A  myA = new B(); 
 B myB = (B) myA; //  такой даун каст прокатит.
```

Но я не могу понять как работают даун касты в подобных случаях когда мы имеем дело с классами из стандартных библиотек. Вот пример:

```
URL conn = new URL("https://www.google.com/");
URLConnection myConect = conn.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection http =(HttpURLConnection)  myConect; // Почему такое разрешается?
```

Подобное возможно потому что это базовые библиотеки или что? Метод openConnection() изначально возвращает URLConnection, поэтому объяснить это изначальным upcastom я не могу. Тогда почему это работает.
В книги Шилдта когда я читал про Number, там было написано, что так как класс является convertible можно делать вещи типа:

```
Number n = 1; // хотя я так думаю это возможно из-за динамической обертки. Наверное по факту это выглядеть как Number n = new Integer
Integer nnn = (Integer) n;
```

Понятно. В классе URLConnection почему такое возможно? Короче, я запутался, господа. Если кто может доходчиво объяснить, буду благодарен. Если можно обьяснение именно на примере класса URLConnection

Comment: `URLConnection` — это абстрактный класс, то есть создать объекты этого класса в принципе невозможно. Следовательно, есть всего два варианта (описанных в документации стандартной библиотеки), какой конкретно класс будет возвращать метод — или `HttpURLConnection`, или `JarURLConnection` (подклассы `URLConnection`). Если в вашем случае метод возвращает `HttpURLConnection`, то такой downcast успешно будет работать. Если же вы попробуете сделать downcast к классу `JarURLConnection`, то получите ошибку, потому что метод возвращает не его

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ